# Importing tf.train.Saver from another python file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use **tf.train.Saver()** in **one.py** file with the following code.

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())
saver.save(sess,"checkpoint.data")
```

How can I restore **checkpoint.data** in another python file?

I used the following code, but it didn't work.

```
from one import saver
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, "checkpoint.data")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkpoint file (i.e. `'checkpoint.data'`) does not provide TensorFlow with enough information to reconstruct your model structure. In your second program, you need to reconstruct the same TensorFlow graph that was used in the first program. There are a few options for doing this:

- Extract the model building code into a Python function, and call it before creating the [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver) in each program.
- Use [`saver.export_meta_graph()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver.export_meta_graph) to write out the graph structure along with a checkpoint in your first program, and [`tf.train.import_meta_graph()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#import_meta_graph) to import the graph structure (and create an appropriately configure `tf.train.Saver` instance) in your second program.